# Is there any way to retrieve Project specific information with Office 365 Management Activity API?

Tags: api, office365, ms-office, ms-project

Recently our team has been using Office 365 Management Activity API. We are trying to Audit MS Project Online, we've encountered a problem with what information is currently being returned.

```
 {
    "CreationTime": "2018-09-18T16:19:04",
    "Id": "xxxxxx-8a46-4c32-ce0b-08d61d8273d4",
    "Operation": "ProjectCheckedOut",
    "OrganizationId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
    "RecordType": 35,
    "UserKey": "i:0h.f|membership|10033fffae7e4ed9@live.com",
    "UserType": 0,
    "Version": 1,
    "Workload": "Project",
    "ClientIP": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "UserId": "xxxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "CorrelationId": "72fa8f9e-903a-0000-1685-17f01beea3eb",
    "EventSource": "Project",
    "ItemType": "Project",
    "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
    "Entity": "Project"
}
```

This is a sample of what these content blobs contains, we don't know if there is a way to add information like project GUID or name, we are fairly new to this API and we haven yet to find any information about this extra content from the DOCs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m afraid that there’s no such API to implement your needs. Please see the following link:
[Troubleshooting the Office 365 Management Activity API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/troubleshooting-the-office-365-management-activity-api)

Answer (score 0):

Very elaborate auditing of Project Online is possible. This is best done in Power BI using the ODATA endpoint. As an example, you could count--or list--"Tasks having a Finish date earlier than Today and Percent Complete not equal 100". There is a multitude of similarlying interesting metrics that can be displayed in tabular and graphical formats in Power BI. These metrics are so powerful that top management can--in a 1-minute review-- gain a very accurate understanding of the quality of any Project Schedule.